# Xml file in jnlp code not working

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, opencv, jnlp

I am having a jnlp file and a web application.My swing application file make use of a xml file in it.Now the problem is where to define that xml file inside jnlp code ? and also where to keep it in my project directory of web application in which am using that jnlp file of swing application.Please help.

I am trying to get over it since one day,But didnt know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can eithere define its jar as a non-lazy download with no part, or make it available as a web resource alongside your jars.

**In the JNLP**

Say you have an XML file `app.xml`, and you added it to the jar `metadata.jar`. Assuming this jar is available at example.com/metadata.jar, you can add this to your JNLP:

```
<jar href="http://example.com/metadata.jar" download="eager" />
```

This will download the metadata jar before your application even starts.

**As a Web Resource**

You can download the XML file directly from your application if you host the XML file on your web server. Once it's hosted, you can then download it as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/).

Comment: I dont have any jar for that xml file,It just xml file being provided by opencv for face recognition,Also i have an image with it

Comment: *"I dont have any jar for that xml file"*  So make one.  Put the image in the Jar as well.